# Express POST Request SyntaxError: Unexpected token o in JSON at position 1

Tags: node.js, json, express

I am trying to get the JSON request body for a POST request using node and express. However, I'm getting this error from express:

```
SyntaxError: Unexpected token o in JSON at position 1
    at JSON.parse (<anonymous>)
    at parse (C:\Users\Bradley\Desktop\test\node_modules\body-parser\lib\types\json.js:89:19)
    at C:\Users\Bradley\Desktop\test\node_modules\body-parser\lib\read.js:121:18
    at invokeCallback (C:\Users\Bradley\Desktop\test\node_modules\raw-body\index.js:224:16)
    at done (C:\Users\Bradley\Desktop\test\node_modules\raw-body\index.js:213:7)
    at IncomingMessage.onEnd (C:\Users\Bradley\Desktop\test\node_modules\raw-body\index.js:273:7)
    at IncomingMessage.emit (events.js:323:22)
    at endReadableNT (_stream_readable.js:1204:12)
    at processTicksAndRejections (internal/process/task_queues.js:84:21)
```

This is all the code I'm running:

```
const express = require('express');
const app = express();
const port = 5680;

app.use(express.json());

app.listen(port, () => {
    console.log(`app listening at http://localhost:${port}`)
});

app.post('/api', (req, res) => {
   console.log(JSON.stringify(req.body));
   return res.sendStatus(200);
});
```

And to trigger the error I'm submitting the request:

```
fetch('http://localhost:5680/api', {
        method: 'POST',
        headers: {'Content-type': 'application/json; charset=UTF-8'},
        body: {"key": "value"}
    }).then(response => console.log(response));
```

It seems like body-parser is double parsing the JSON, but I can't figure out why.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The issue is with the request. The body should be a string, so the full request is:

```
fetch('http://localhost:5680/api', {
        method: 'POST',
        headers: {'Content-type': 'application/json; charset=UTF-8'},
        body: '{"key": "value"}'
    }).then(response => console.log(response));
```